# Override default_error_messages on SlugRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

From the django-rest-framework documentation:

> Each serializer field class constructor takes at least these arguments. Some Field classes take additional, field-specific arguments, but the following should always be accepted:
>
> - error_messages - A dictionary of error codes to error messages.

I have attempted to override the "does_not_exist" error message in a SlugRelatedField like so:

```
example = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='label', error_messages={"does_not_exist": "Some custom error message."})
```

and receive the error:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

Any tips on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rendered the following way:

```
raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['does_not_exist'] %
                              (self.slug_field, smart_text(data)))
```

So it forces you to include two `%s` placeholders.

This is the default:

```
'does_not_exist': _("Object with %s=%s does not exist."),
```

If you want to omit the `%s` arguments, then there's no other way except for overriding the whole `from_native`.

Comment: Was just reading through the source and noticed that. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 8):

I think django-rest-framework has changed how this works since this question was asked.

Using DRF version 3.8.2, the default error messages for `SlugRelatedField` are now:

```
default_error_messages = {
    'does_not_exist': _('Object with {slug_name}={value} does not exist.'),
    'invalid': _('Invalid value.'),
}
```

I was able to successfully override the does_not_exist error simply by:

```
field = SlugRelatedField(
    error_messages={
        'does_not_exist': 'Foo error field={value} does not exist.',
    }
)
```

Note how I'm only using one of the values DRF inserts into the string - `value`, and I'm not using `slug_name`. This works fine.

Comment: If using `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, you have to interpolate `pk_value` instead ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3f19e66d9f2569895af6e91455e5cf53b8ce5640/rest_framework/relations.py#L241)).

Comment: How the value gets inserted into string? There's no f letter before string?

Comment: DRF effectively does `error_string.format(value=foo)` to insert the value into the string

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to override the sane error but in DRF ModelSerializer.
Just look at that: my case where field promo_code is Fk to another model, to override does_not_exist error we schould do the following:

```
    class Meta:
        model = models.ActivePromoCode
        fields = ('promo_code', )
        extra_kwargs = {"promo_code": {"error_messages": {"does_not_exist": "promocode_not_found"}}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).